# SharePoint 2013 Form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

I need to create a form in SharePoint server 2013 on a separate page (I don't need to customize the form when clicking on add new item). Then, I would like to save the data coming from the Form's fields into a custom list so I can develop a workflow from my form. Can anyone provide me with any help on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom scripts on the save button on the form where you can call REST Services with method POST to add the data in the SharePoint list. Check out REST API's example to add items in a list. there are lots of tutorial available.

Comment: What type of application I need to start with from visual studio, is it app for SharePoint or SharePoint Solution ?

Comment: no kind of application. just open your page in SharePoint designer and refer jquery files and your custom javascript.js file. To write javascript you can take a .txt file write your script in there and then save it as .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Our department has use the jQuery SPServices library. You can use this for all CRUD operations. The script is written in a .txt file and then uploaded to the site. You can then use the Content Editor web part to reference the file and run the script. The jQuery SPServices library has many built in function to CRUD lists.

https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetListItems&referringTitle=Lists

I liked Ankit's suggestion to use the API. This is simply another way to slice the apple.

Answer (score 0):

If You just need to copy Fields values, yes the worflow is a good and simple solution.

You Can just use : Sharepoint designer. With this tool, You Can add workflows on your list (when an item is added). And off course you can design your workflow (to get Fields value, and creat new item in jour other list)

There is other solutions.
If You Can deploy wsp, You create Visual studio solution (farm solution) and add an évent réciter on jour list. Or use JavaScript with the JSOM (javascript Sharepoint object model). Or create custom list form ...